# Using predict.rma with categorical and continuous moderators and their interactions

Tags: r, interaction, prediction, meta-analysis

I'm trying to predict new variables using the predict.rma function of the metafor package. My model has continuous and categorical variables and their interactions. Here is an example using the BCG data:

```
dat.bcg$alloc <- factor(dat.bcg$alloc)  
res <- rma(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, 
           mods = ~ ablat + alloc + ablat:alloc, data=dat.bcg)  
preds <- predict(model,
newmods=cbind(rep(c(10,20,30,40),times=3), # for ablat 
c(rep(0,4),rep(1,4),rep(0,4)), # for allocrandom
c(rep(0,8),rep(1,4)), # for allocsystematic
rep(c(10,20,30,40),times=3)*c(rep(0,4),rep(1,4),rep(0,4)), # for ablat.allocrandom 
rep(c(10,20,30,40),times=3)*c(rep(0,8),rep(1,4))), addx=T) # for ablat.allocsystematic
```

Unfortunately, I get the error message:

```
Error in predict.rma(model, newmods = cbind(rep(c(10, 20, 30, 40), times = 3),  : 
  Dimensions of 'newmods' do not match dimensions of the model.
```

Any ideas why this happens and how to modify the code?

Comment: Questions about how to use R code (eg, error messages) are off topic here. This should be on topic on [SO]. If you wait, we will try to migrate it there.

Comment: Or try posting it on R-help where either I or the author of the package will answer it.

Comment: You called the model `res` but then used `predict(model, ...)`. If you use `predict(res, ...)` it works as intended. You probably had another model object called `model` floating around, so you didn't get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with the functions in question, but at first glance you provide a formula containing `ablat`, `alloc` and their interaction, but in the data you provide as `newmods`, you have `alblat`, `allocrandom`, `allocsystematic` and the interactions of those latter two with `ablat`.

So you created a model with 3 variables (+ maybe an intercept), but you try to predict with 5 variables.

So make sure your formula in the model corresponds with the data you provide in predict.